# Magento 2 : Change Store view programmatically at front end side

Tags: magento2, store-view, magento2.3.1

I want to change store view programmatically same as like when we switch store from store switcher at front end side.

I try this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176710/77631). But, it's not working. It's just change store view name from store switcher dropdown.

How to implement it?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Hi @Ankita patel did u find any solution for this issue. It yes, advise me on 
this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/352843/how-to-change-store-based-on-country-location-magento2

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution to change store view programmatically

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Api\StoreCookieManagerInterface $_storeCookieManager
 */
protected $_storeCookieManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $_storeRepository
 */
protected $_storeRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Api\StoreCookieManagerInterface $storeCookieManager,
    \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
) {
    $this->_storeCookieManager = $storeCookieManager;
    $this->_storeRepository = $storeRepository;
}

public function execute(){
    $store = $this->_storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode('store_view_code');
    $this->_storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);
}
```

Comment: Same issue. Not working :(

Comment: Where you are using this code? in controller or what?

Comment: in observer. event : layout_load_before.

Comment: can you please help me to solve this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290067/error-in-add-or-update-a-cart-in-magento-2 @ranganathan

Comment: @Ranganathan can u advise me on this issue plz https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/352843/how-to-change-store-based-on-country-location-magento2